# How to make an ImageList of a folder from the internet?

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api

I have looked everywhere for the answer but couldn't find it. What I am trying to do is take a folder of Google Drive and put it into my image list. The folder is a shared folder so I am uncertain if I can just use the Google Drive folder on my computer that is used for syncing to my Drive.

Comment: Yes, you can use the local folder of images

Comment: Ok, but will the other users be able to see the images, the reason I wanted to use the site is because it is not a directory, and I thought since the other users will never have the same directory as me it would just show nothing.

Comment: This is a classic case of a question that needs more focus, i.e. it's really a combination of multiple questions. Creating and populating an `ImageList` is the same no matter where the images come from. Your question is whether multiple machines can see the same cloud drive, which probably doesn't even have anything to do with VB.NET or programming at all. If you can map that folder locally on two machines then you have your answer about whether multiple users can see the same folder. If you can access any file in that folder in VB.NET then you know that your app can do that. That's it done.

Comment: Thanks jmcihinney that was very helpful

Comment: How do I make your comment an answer?

Comment: I posted comment *@jmcilhinney* as a community wiki answer. I'll remove it if  *@jmcilhinney* posted own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accordingly to the comment posted by @jmcilhinney.

> This is a classic case of a question that needs more focus, i.e. it's
> really a combination of multiple questions. Creating and populating an
> ImageList is the same no matter where the images come from. Your
> question is whether multiple machines can see the same cloud drive,
> which probably doesn't even have anything to do with VB.NET or
> programming at all. If you can map that folder locally on two machines
> then you have your answer about whether multiple users can see the
> same folder. If you can access any file in that folder in VB.NET then
> you know that your app can do that. That's it done.